# Как сделать перестановки в матрицах смежности графов так, чтобы они стали подобны?

Tags: c++, графы

Мне нужно написать алгоритм проверки изоморфности графов. (Сложность алгоритма можно любую, например O(n!) ).
В одной из статей есть теорема которая звучит так:

*Теорема 1. Графы изоморфны тогда и только тогда, когда их матрицы смежности перестановочно подобны, то есть их можно получить одну из другой перестановками строк и соответствующих столбцов.*

Как можно максимально просто сделать перестановки в матрицах смежности так, чтобы они стали подобны?

UPD. Пытаюсь вывести все перестановки одного графа. Я не понимаю как работает next_permutation(), он выводит не все перестановки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Graph {
private:
    bool** adjMatrix;
    int numVertices;
public:
    Graph(int numVertices) {
        this->numVertices = numVertices;
        adjMatrix = new bool* [numVertices];
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            adjMatrix[i] = new bool[numVertices];
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                adjMatrix[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    int getNumVertices() {
        return numVertices;
    }

    void addEdge(int i, int j) {
        adjMatrix[i][j] = true;
        adjMatrix[j][i] = true;
    }

    void removeEdge(int i, int j) {
        adjMatrix[i][j] = false;
        adjMatrix[j][i] = false;
    }

    void toString() {
        cout << "toString" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            cout << i << " : ";
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                cout << adjMatrix[i][j] << " ";
            cout << "\n";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void nextPer() {
        cout << "nextPer" << endl;
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
                cout << i << " : ";
                for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                    cout << adjMatrix[i][j] << " ";
                cout << "\n";
            }
            cout << endl;
        } while (next_permutation(adjMatrix, adjMatrix + numVertices));
        cout << "nextPer after next_permutation" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            cout << i << " : ";
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                cout << adjMatrix[i][j] << " ";
            cout << "\n";
        }
        cout << endl;
        
    }

    ~Graph() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
            delete[] adjMatrix[i];
        delete[] adjMatrix;
    }
};
int main() {
    Graph g(4);

    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 0);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.toString();
    g.nextPer();
}
```

Comment: Если O(n!) - просто выполнять поочередно и проверять **все** перестановки, какая-то да окажется нужной :)

Comment: @Harry а как выполнять собственно эти перестановки и как их проверить? Я пока только учусь :)

Comment: Ну, раз у вас C++ - просто использовать `next_permutation()`, собрать новую матрицу и сравнить. Причем можно сравнивать прямо по ходу - несовпадение - переходим к следующей. Но только даже для n~10 это уже очень напряжно по времени... Так что надо смотреть и отбрасывать целые пачки перестановок, у которых сразу выявляется несовпадение...

Comment: @Harry подскажите пожалуйста, я приложил выше код